# "The cma file is not a bytecode object file" => What does that mean?

Tags: sqlite, ocaml

I'm trying to install the ocaml-sqlite3 bindings, to access a sqlite database from an o'caml program.

The configure and make go smoothly, but the installation fails. Because the file sqlite3.cma is not a bytecode object file (see below).

```
    ~/Software/ocaml-sqlite3-release-1.5.6> sudo make install

[ -f *.so ] && SO_FILES=*.so; \
        ocamlfind install sqlite3 META sqlite3.cmi sqlite3.mli sqlite3.cma *.cmxa *.a *.cmx $SO_FILES
Installed /usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3/dllsqlite3_stubs.so
Installed /usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3/sqlite3.cmx
Installed /usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3/sqlite3.a
Installed /usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3/libsqlite3_stubs.a
Installed /usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3/sqlite3.cmxa
Installed /usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3/sqlite3.cma
Installed /usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3/sqlite3.mli
Installed /usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3/sqlite3.cmi
Installed /usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3/META
Updated /usr/lib64/ocaml/ld.conf
ocamlfind ocamlmktop -o sqlite3top -package "sqlite3" sqlite3.cma
The file sqlite3.cma is not a bytecode object file
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

What is the general reason for that and have you experienced that for this particular lib ? 
I'm running ocaml v 3.11.1 compiled from source.

**EDIT:**
It seems the file is provided by ocamlfind, maybe the problem is due to the fact that i'm using a 64 environment ?

Comment: I've seen this kind of error before, but unfortunately I don't remember what caused it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it seems the problem was coming from different directions:

First, the ocaml compiler used by ocamlfind was not the right. I've figured that out by looking at the /usr/local/etc/findlib.conf. The ocamlc was pointing towards ocamlopt.opt and that was version 3.10.

Then, I had to recompile findlib. But there was a problem because I'm on a 64 architectures and some elements were not found, so I had to reconfigure findlib modifying -bindir and -sitelib mainly.

I've also recompiled the ocaml system with -cc "gcc -m64" but I'm not sure it has any effect.

Now, it works but i've to use -I to add the directory of sqlite3.cma (/usr/lib64/ocaml/site-lib/sqlite3).

Not sure that could help anybody though :-).

Answer (score 2):

Usually this error appears when ocaml compiler attempts to use binary files (cma,cmo,etc) created by another version of ocaml. In particular, it means that you need to recompile *all* the libraries when upgrading ocaml (even with minor version shift like 3.11.0 -> 3.11.1).

Could that be that ocamlfind invoked different ocaml installations at `make` and `make install` stages?

Comment: yep you're right, this is what i wrote in my answer, the /usr/local/etc/findlib.conf was using ocamlopt.opt which pointed to an older version of ocaml.